# When is orthogonal projection compact?

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, orthogonality, compact-operators

Let $M$ be a closed subspace of a Hilbert space $H$. Let $P$ be the orthogonal projection on $M$. I was told to find the eigenvalues and eigenvectors of $P$ and moreover say when it is compact.

Since $M$ is closed we have $H\cong M\oplus M^\perp$ and this is an eigenspace decomposition so $P$ has eigenvalues $1,0$ and eigenvectors the elements of $M,M^\perp$ respectively. Is there any formal explanation I emphasize in the infinite dimensional case?

If $M$ is finite dimensional $P$ is finite rank so compact. I don't see anything but that...

Comment: An operator $T$ is compact if and only if $T(B)$ is compact, where $B$ is the closed unit ball...

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich I don't know how to use that to find some conditions on $M$ in this generality.

Comment: Well, if $P$ is the orthogonal projection onto $M$ what _is_ $T(B)$? It's easy to figure out what $T(B)$ is, and then it's clear that $T(B)$ is compact if annd only ig $M$ is ...